# Can I run successive MySQL subqueries conditionally?

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements, subquery

I currently have PHP code that runs a single complex query, with subqueries, in hopes of finding 12 matching records. If less than 12 records are returned, the code runs a second version of the same query, with a slightly modified WHERE clause, to add to the records previously retrieved by the first query. It continues running modified versions of the query until a grand total of 12 records are assembled.

I know that I could combine the multiple queries -- there are currently five -- with a UNION, but then all of the queries get run even if the first query in the union is successful in returning 12 records. Since each query is complex, I don't want to waste the resources. (Or, am I wrong about that? Does MySQL know to stop executing subqueries once a LIMIT is reached?)

Is there a way in MySQL to accomplish what I'm currently doing in PHP? For instance, how can I have a query with five subqueries, and progress through successive subqueries only if the preceding subqueries don't produce a desired count?

Comment: wouldn't a stored procedure do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [stored procedure](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3547931/MySQL-Stored-Procedures-Part-2.htm) on the server that does this check quite simply.